# Java Auto Cast an Object

Tags: java, casting

I'm wondering if there is a way to Auto Cast an Object to some type by storing the Class type along with the object? I thought this was possible with Java, but maybe not.

For example:

```
class StorageItem
{
    private int itemcount;

    StorageItem(int itemcount)
    {
        this.itemcount = itemcount;
    }

    int getItemCount()
    {
        return itemcount;
    }
}

class Storage
{
    private Class clazz;

    private Object value;

    public Storage(Class clazz, Object value)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.value = value;
    }

    //Is there a way such a call can be created to automatically cast 
    //the object to the class type and return that cast type in a 
    //generic way. The idea being that Storage knows what it should
    //already be cast to. Is this possible?
    public T getValue()
    {
        return clazz.cast(value);
    }
}
```

A usage example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Create storage item
    Storage storage = new Storage(StorageItem.class, new StorageItem(1234));

    //The call to getValue() will automatically cast to the Class passed
    //into Storage.
    int itemcount = storage.getValue().getItemCount(); //returns 1234
}
```

Obviously the getValue() call in Storage is a pseudocode call, but it's just there to provide the idea as to what I would like to do.

Is there anyway to have a getValue() call that will Auto cast to the Class typed stored in the Storage class. Again, the idea is that the Storage class knows what it should be cast to. Or is there anyway this can be done at all?

StorageItem is just one simple example. Here, it just stores an int for discussion purposes. However, it could be more complex.

Another usage example, would be storing the Storage object in a list.

```
List<Storage> row = new ArrayList<Storage>();
row.add(new Storage(StorageItem.class, 1234));
row.add(new Storage(String.class, "Jason"));
row.add(new Storage(Integer.class, 30));
row.add(new Storage(Double.class, 12.7));
```

Then, these can be accessed in the following way.

```
//calls StorageItem's getItemCount() method
row.get(0).getValue().getItemCount(); //returns 1234

//calls String's length() method
row.get(1).getValue().length(); //returns 5

//calls Integer's intValue() method
row.get(2).getValue().intValue(); 

//calls Integer's doubleValue() method
row.get(3).getValue().doubleValue();
```

If getValue() only ever returned an Object, I would have to always cast to the specific Object manually. Instead, if I can store the cast class inside the Storage object, then Storage has enough information to know what to automatically cast the Object to on the getValue() call.

If this is doable in Java is the answer to the question I'm seeking. And if so, how?

Comment: Why won't you use a simple generic class?

Comment: Why `Storage storage = new Storage(StorageItem.class, new StorageItem(1234));` instead of `StorageItem storageItem = new StorageItem(1234);`?

Comment: Change `class Storage { ...` and `private Object value` to `class Storage<T> { ...` resp. `private T value;` and you're all set.

Comment: I'd like to avoid directly casting the Object type if it can be done automatically for me. Since Storage knows what class it should cast itself too, I'm not sure if a method could be written to Auto Cast to the Class that was passed into the Storage object. Please see my recent updates above.

Comment: What you're asking to do here can't be done: there is no way that the compiler can know that `row.get(0)` is an instance of a "`StorageItem`-bearing" `Storage`, rather than a "`String`-bearing" `Storage`.

Comment: @AndyT: row.get(0) returns Storage not a StorageItem. It's the getValue() call that is in question as to IF the getValue() call can be written in such a way to auto cast upon the call to getValue() the Class type (variable name 'clazz' in Storage) and cast the Object. In other words, the idea would be for getValue() to return a StorageItem if 'clazz' was passed in as a StorageItem class.

Comment: @JasonF yes. That's why I say "a "`StorageItem`-bearing" `Storage`": an instance of `Storage` which bears a reference to a `StorageItem`.

Comment: @AndyT: I stand corrected. I see now you were referring to the StorageItem referenced in Storage. Ok, so it seems clear that what I was thinking could be done is not doable. Despite Storage knowing the Class type and has a reference to it, no getValue() method could be written to auto cast the Object to the Class type the Storage Object has a reference too. Very good! You've answered my question =). And, I'm very grateful!

Answer (score 6):

Would this do the trick? Much less hacking is required:

```
class Storage<T> {

    private T value;

    public Storage(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not only is much less hacking required, it also works with generic types, like `List<String>`, for which no non-raw class instance exists.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the problem that you're trying to solve here. @bali182's answer does give you a "generic" way to store a reference - but storing the  reference itself is just easier.

Consider what happens if you put two `Storage` instances, containing differently-typed references, into a collection:

```
List<Storage<SOMETHING>> storages = new ArrayList<>();
storages.add(new Storage<String>("Hello"));
storages.add(new Storage<Integer>(1));
```

So: what is `SOMETHING`? Well, it has to be `?`, since that is the only type which satisfies both elements.

Now, when you iterate through the list to retrieve them, you have to deal with them as `Object`:

```
for (Storage<?> storage : storages) {
  Object object = storage.getValue();
  // ...
}
```

because you don't, in general, know what the type of the stored reference is for any given element. The concrete type of `object` will be the concrete type of the element - `String` and `Integer`, for the list above - but you can't make use of these different types without using some means to detect that type (e.g. `if (object instanceof String)`).

It would just have been easier if the references were stored directly in the list:

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
storages.add("Hello");
storages.add(1;
for (Object object : objects) {
  // ...
}
```

You still would have to do something to detect the concrete type of object; you're just doing it without the extra layer of indirection.

---

Although the above example is for unrelated types, it's still easier to do it with the direct references if they are the same type:

```
List<String> objects = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World");
for (String object : objects) {
  // ...
}
```

Now you don't need to do anything to know the concrete type (you *might*, if the elements were of a non-final class, and you wanted to handle some subclasses specially), but you've still avoided needing to dereference `Storage.getValue()` to get at a value that you could have directly instead.

Comment: "because you don't, in general, know what the type of the stored reference is for any given element. The concrete type of object will be the concrete type of the element". Exactly, unless Storage knows what concrete type to cast it to. You can see that I passed in the Concrete type. So, Storage now knows that SOMETHING to cast it to. See my updates I recently posted. What I may be trying to do may not be possible. But, that's why I'm asking, since I don't know if there is a way. =)

Comment: @JasonF the *compiler* doesn't know the type of the stored object, but the stored object knows its own type, which you can retrieve using `getClass()`. Bear in mind that casting doesn't create a new object - it just says to the compiler "you think this is an `Object`, but trust me, I know it's a `String`". In other words, `object == (String) object` is `true`, assuming `object.getClass() == String.class`.

Comment: @ AndyT, BTW thanks for your input on this. Right, casting doesn't create an new Object. The only way getItemCount() will be callable, is if the Object was understood to be of type StorageItem. You can see how I'm using the getValue call above. If the getValue can auto cast to the StorageItem, then getItemCount() would be callable. How this can be done or IF this can be done is not known to me in Java. If it can be done in some way, then how? If not, then why?

Comment: "If not, then why?" Because that's the way that Java's type system works.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying there's no way for getValue() in Storage to be written that will Auto Cast the Object to the Class type that Storage is storing. If it can't be done, it can't be done. It's why I'm asking =)

Comment: Not quite: provided you have `Storage` instances with the same generic type, the instance stored can be "automatically cast" to that type (and there is a cast, for @bali182's class: because of erasure it *is* stored as an `Object` reference, but cast in the calling code); you just can't do it to heterogeneous types when the `Storage` instances are stored in the same container; but you get nothing from the additional overhead of the `Storage` class.